# Onscreen Rendering as well as Offscreen Rendering of electron window

Tags: bitmap, electron, render, off-screen

I liked the [Offscreen Rendering](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/offscreen-rendering) feature of electron app. I can render window content to image so easily with this feature.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')

app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

let win

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { offscreen: true } })

  win.loadURL('https://github.com')
  win.webContents.on('paint', (event, dirty, image) => {
    fs.writeFileSync('my_image.png', image.toPNG())
  })
  win.webContents.setFrameRate(60)
})
```

By default `offscreen` is `false` so content renders on the screen.

How can I see content of window `on screen` as well as `off screen`(image `my_image.png`) in such a way that when I perform some action on `window`(Onscreen) that should reflect on `my_image.png`(Offscreen) also?

Comment: so to be clear, does the `paint` event not fire when off screen, or is the image not correct?

Comment: [related?](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22357) and [related](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16288)

Comment: @pushkin when `offscreen` is `false` paint is not fired

Comment: I'd post an issue with Electron